# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got CHAR

Tags: oracle, timestamp, date-arithmetic

```
SELECT COALESCE (
      (to_timestamp( '2014-09-22 16:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')
        -   ('2014-09-22   09:00:00' ,'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS'))  
        - (to_timestamp( '2014-09-22 16:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')  
        - to_timestamp('2014-09-22 09:00:00.' ,'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')) 
       , '00:00') 
FROM DUAL;
```

This is working in postgres but it is not working in oracle.

Comment: remove . from this line to_timestamp('2014-09-22 09:00:00.' ,'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS'))

Comment: Use `to_date`, timestamp is not required. Check my answer!

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you are trying to do maths (+, -) with TIMESTAMP.
TIMESTAMP doesn't like that. you should CAST the TIMESTAMP to DATE:

rather than
`bla - blu` (where bla and blu are TIMESTAMP) do

`CAST (bla as DATE) - CAST (blu as DATE)`

and you will get a NUMBER (multiply it by 3600 * 24 and you will turn it into seconds)

BUT
you will lose the millisecond info

check this link [timestamp difference](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1602071-difference-between-two-timestamps)

Here you have the  [definition of the TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm)

Comment: there is nothing wrong in using the time part of the `DATE`. Every date has a time part, thus, subtracting two dates will take care of the time part as well.

Comment: yes, there is nothing wrong but (+,-) with to_timestamp is wrong, that is why we have to cast the timestamp to date

Comment: A simple to_date instead of to_timestamp wold suffice.

Comment: You can subtract one timestamp from another, as your first link shows; you just [get an interval back](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#g196492) rather than a number. You can't add them though.

Answer (score 3):

Change `'00:00'` to `INTERVAL '0' DAY`:

```
SELECT COALESCE (
  (to_timestamp('2014-09-22 16:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') - to_timestamp('2014-09-22 09:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')) -
  (to_timestamp('2014-09-22 16:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') - to_timestamp('2014-09-22 09:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')),
  INTERVAL '0' DAY)
FROM DUAL;
```

More info: [Interval Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221)

Comment: I don't see the use of `COALESCE` with a single expression to check. `NVL` is enough.

Comment: As demonstrated by the error using `COALESCE()` has stopped the OP from potentially being caught out by an incorrect implicit conversion, which `NVL()` would not have done @Lalit. `COALESCE()` works with only 2 expressions and as it stops implicit conversion there's no real problem here.

Comment: @Ben, even `NVL` would throw the error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got CHAR`

Comment: @LalitKumarB `COALESCE` is supported by many SQL servers, `NVL` is specific to Oracle. So I prefer `COALESCE` here.

Answer (score 1):

1. With only one expressions to check, `COALESCE` is not required.
   `NVL` would suffice. Basically, if there is no time difference, it
   would return 0.
2. `DATE` has a time part, the `TIMESTAMP` datatype is an extension on
   the DATE datatype. In addition to the datetime elements of the DATE
   datatype, the TIMESTAMP datatype holds fractions of a second to a
   precision between 0 and 9 decimal places, the default being 6. So,
   in your case, `TO_DATE` makes more sense.

> ```
> SQL> SELECT NVL(
>       2            (to_date( '2014-09-22 16:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date('2014-09-22 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
>       3           - (to_date('2014-09-22 16:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date('2014-09-22 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
>       4          ,0) DIFF
>       5  FROM DUAL
>       6  /
>
>           DIFF
>     ----------
>              0
>
>     SQL>
> ```

For other values, to get a significant difference of time interval :

```
SQL> SELECT NVL(
  2            (to_date( '2014-09-22 16:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date('2014-09-22 23:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
  3           - (to_date('2014-09-22 16:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date('2014-09-22 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
  4          ,0) DIFF
  5  FROM DUAL
  6  /

      DIFF
----------
-.58333333
```

**Update**

Since the difference of the dates returns a number, using `NVL` with `TO_DATE` won't return `interval` but a `number`. As, in above example, it is 0.

To get the interval in the difference, `to_timestamp` makes sense. So, NVL and TO_TIMESTAMP would be good :

```
SQL> SELECT NVL (
  2    (to_timestamp('2014-09-22 16:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') - to_timestamp('2014-09-22 09:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')) -
  3    (to_timestamp('2014-09-22 16:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') - to_timestamp('2014-09-22 09:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')),
  4    INTERVAL '0' DAY) diff
  5  FROM DUAL
  6  /

DIFF
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000000 00:00:00.000000000
```